# Azure Batch Pool Stuck on Start Up Task

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-batch, azure-batch-account

Hi everyone currently I am working on automating installation of certain application in one of our pool node in Azure Batch using application package.

For this example I am just trying to install google chrome in one our node but the node keeps getting stuck in waiting the startup task. The start up task is very simple as

```
cmd /c %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_CHROME#95%\\ChromeSetup.exe -args -here
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please make certain that your installer is able to install in a non-interactive mode. For Google Chrome, [this may help](https://superuser.com/questions/337210/how-can-i-silently-install-google-chrome).

Comment: I've tried this approach already and still fails to install the google chrome after RDP to node.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the it requires you to elevate the user access level to admin. It was not highlighted in documentation when using application package in batch account.

Just add this in your json config when deploying batch account node.

[image]

Comment: Installing a program does not always require privilege elevation.

Comment: Yes agree, thats the case when I am testing on my local silent install work just fine. Unfortunately for azure batch this what works for me :)